# PDF Design Creation with JavaFx

Tags: java, html, pdf, javafx, document

I creating an application with JavaFx and in it I want to create pdf files with my own design/theme. So the user should entry data into textfields in the javafx application, and with this unformatted data the application should create a (complex) pdf document. Maybe is comparable with creating a pdf with LaTex.

So I don't know what's the best way to create such documents with java. First ideas where using html or xml but i hope you can give me some tipps or show me a more efficient way of creating and desinging pdf documents from javaFx.

Comment: try this https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library or directly https://itextpdf.com/

Comment: I believe this is too broad a question for StackOverflow (please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). That said, when faced with a similar problem I eventually chose creating HTML and converting it using wkhtmltopdf.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking for a recommendation, you might want to head to the [StackExchange Software Recs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdf+java) site which is for that purpose.

Software I've seen successfully used to create PDFs from Java applications includes iText (programmatic), Docmosis [please note I work for Docmosis] (templates) , Jasper Reports (xml/gui), wkhtmltopdf (conversion), Windward (templates) and Aspose (code).  Which would suit you is down to a number of other requirements which are not in your problem description.

Hope that helps.